# Manually resolving a RedirectToRouteResult to a View Result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

For a project I am working on, I'm implementing some feature tests in SpecFlow 1.9.2.

The problem I am encountering with these tests is that I am getting a Null Reference exception upon trying to cast an ActionResult to a ViewResult.  The reason this problem exists, however, is because in our controller, we have two code paths like so:

```
public class CurrentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(MyModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction", "Current");
        }

        // Views will be omitted as they're irrelevant to my question.
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
    {
        SomeModel model = new SomeModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

...In my feature test, I have a step to invoke the HTTP post:

```
public class MyFeatureTest
{
    private ActionResult _actionResult;
    private ViewResult _viewResult;

    private MyModel _myModel;
    private SomeModel _someModel;

    // SNIP: Other steps unnecessary to this problem description...

    [When(@"I click save on the first action")]
    public void WhenIClickSaveOnTheFirstAction()
    {
        _actionResult = _currentController.SomeAction(_myModel);
        _viewResult = _actionResult as ViewResult;  // Evaluates to null
        _someModel = _viewResult.ViewData.Model as SomeModel;
    }
}
```

Upon trying to assign `_someModel`, the NullReference exception is thrown.

To attempt to circumvent the issue I tried changing the `RedirectToAction` call in the HTTP post to a direct call on `SomeOtherAction`, but this caused a site error.

**Question**: As stated above, the core of my problem is that a RedirectToRouteResult is not a ViewResult.  In the context of a feature test, what are some ways I would resolve a RedirectToRouteResult to get the controller to produce the appropriate ViewResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `ModelState.IsValid` will return true, which causes the RedirectToRouteResult instead of carrying on and returning the ViewResult.

You could try calling `_currentController.ModelState.AddModelError()` to force the `ModelState.IsValid` to return false.